# Reactjs is unable to establish socket connection, it opens and getting response while calling on componentDidMount

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I am unable to open web socket connection in React.js. Connection establishes while calling the same function in componentDidMount. When I start calling using any event like onClick or onSubmit, I am unable to open connection and get response from server.

The code is below.

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket('wss://api.somedomain.io/WSGateway');

class MyClass extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.authenticate();
  }
  authenticate() {
    exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
      var payload = {
        "UserName": "username",
        "Password": "password"
      };
      var msg = {
        "m": 0,
        "i": 0,
        "n": "AuthenticateUser",
        "o": JSON.stringify(payload)
      };
      exampleSocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function apiAuthenticateUser(event) {
      try {
        let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        let o_data = JSON.parse(data["o"]);
        console.log(o_data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
render() {
  const { classes, theme } = this.props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        name="authentication"
        id="testid1"
        onClick={(e) => {
          this.authenticate(e);
        }}
      >
        Login
        </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
}
export default MyClass;
```

Comment: @halfer - thanks for the suggestions and issue is still open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid your `authenticate` method is not binded to the component's scope. Use bind in constructor or simply use arrow function on declaration:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.authenticate();
  }

  authenticate = () => {
    exampl...
```

In the onClick simply use in this format:

```
     <button
       ...
       onClick={this.authenticate}
     >
```

Comment: just a moment let me try that way

Comment: 1. added in constructor 
this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this);
2. Changed to 
authenticate = () => { }
but same response

Comment: React-wise either 1 or 2 should (but not both) should be implemented. In this case  another, socket-related error is happening on top of this.

Comment: i tried point number 1 first and later 2 ,
yes this is something related socket but with the same function getting proper response while calling it with componentDidMount() - that is why i am getting confused

Comment: was able to resolve the issue with the DOM element - Socket was opening in actual DOM first and later using Virtual dom i just synchronized both